# Eclipse vrapper undo

Tags: eclipse, vim

I use Eclipse for programming in almost any language. I also like the vim shortcuts for quick editing so I installed vrapper.
The problem is when I write a lot of code, and I just want to undo some little things. It undos a lot of chunks of code back, instead of 2 or 3 little things.
I've found some threads which seem to resolve my issue by using "set noati", but it does nothing. It doesn't matter if I use "Ctrl+Z" or "u" from vim command mode.
Can someone please help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Did you try vrapper's issue tracker?

Answer (score 4):

The `set noati` seems to be the solution for that (at least was for me and other people in vrapper forums)... simply to update to the latest version of vrapper then you either specific the `set noati` (no ":" here!) in the ".vrapperrc" (this config file should be placed in your home directory) or you simply run the `:set noati` command from Eclipse vrapper.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two things that might help you.

1) Stay out of insert mode.

The way undo works is in terms of vim commands. So if you change to insert mode and type a hundred words, that counts as a single command. On the other hand, if you press escape every once in a while to get out of insert mode, undo will behave much more pleasantly.

Once you get more familiar with vim, you will want to do less and less in a single insert. So the undo problem will likely be reduced as well.

2) Temporarily disable vrapper via the toolbar icon.

This is an alternative if you absolutely need the default undo behaviour of Eclipse.